# NSUserDefaults clears its value after specific time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsuserdefaults

I save my dictionary using **NSUserDefaults** as follow:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// unarchive
NSData *newData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"];
NSDictionary *newDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

**Problem:** The dicitionary contains a name value with some other values, but after specific time period (mostly after 24 Hours), the name values gives me " "(blank) value.

I see this kind of issue first time, help me to solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be writing an archived object to `NSUserDefaults`, instead use a `.plist` to persist your `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Have you checked whether NSdata have any data or not...If newData log any value except nil or null then may be problem in unarchiving or archiving....

Comment: where you have placed this snipet in your iOS code.

Comment: maybe your data will be updated after some time. otherwise this won't occur.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in this pice of code.

1) Try to check if your application contains `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"key"]` in another classes/methods.

2) Check if `NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];` is not empty when you are writing it (Maybe it get's corrupted, and wipes the already written data).
To check the issue you can make a small versioning and debug the issue, here is the code.

```
    NSMutableArray *datas = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"datas"] mutableCopy];
    if (!datas) {
        datas = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];
    [datas addObject:data];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:datas forKey:@"datas"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // Debug code to see the result
    NSLog(@"======= Logging saved datas");
    for (NSData *data in datas) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        NSLog(@"%@", dict);
    }
```

This code will allow you to see all the versions of dictionaries saved in `NSUserDefaults`, and probably you will get the moment when Empty data is saved.

Comment: This is a (admittedly long) comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Droppy you're right, but i think this will help to resolve issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but it working properly on same day even after closes / terminate app many times.

Answer (score 0):

I think you place your code where it is called again after you save for first time and load next time but then your nsdata object is empty.

**Scenario :**

1st time run app it will save the prefrences

Close the application completely.and then again open your application it again save prefrences while your nsdata object is empty

**Edit**

**Why you not save dictionary directly in NSUserDefaults?**

Comment: Thanks for your reply...
but it working properly on same day even after closes / terminate app many times.

Comment: i didn't see any kind of instruction from apple otherwise they can't give the liberty to save any kind of object in nsuserdefault.
Apple already have better structure than ours.

Comment: also dictionary should be mutable while adding object in it.